# Panda3D & Python Error: IOError Could not load Model File(s)

Tags: python, panda3d

Im trying to create a Panda3D with Python Scene, When I try to run my Python Code, I get this:

http://tinypic.com/r/15duueg/8

Here's my code:

```
from direct.actor.Actor import Actor
from pandac.PandaModules import *
from direct.task import Task
import math
from math import pi, sin, cos
from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase
from direct.task import Task
from direct.interval.IntervalGlobal import Sequence
from pandac.PandaModules import Point3
from pandac.PandaModules import *

import direct.directbase.DirectStart
from panda3d.core import CollisionTraverser,CollisionNode
from panda3d.core import CollisionHandlerQueue,CollisionRay
from panda3d.core import Filename,AmbientLight,DirectionalLight
from panda3d.core import PandaNode,NodePath,Camera,TextNode
from panda3d.core import Vec3,Vec4,BitMask32
from direct.gui.OnscreenText import OnscreenText
from direct.actor.Actor import Actor
from direct.showbase.DirectObject import DirectObject

#Base Toontown Central
terrain = loader.loadModel('phase_4/models/neighborhoods/toontown_central.bam')
terrain.setPos(9.15527e-005, -1.90735e-006, 2.6226e-006)
terrain.setHpr(-90, 0, -0)
terrain.reparentTo(render)
terrain.setTransparency(TransparencyAttrib.MBinary, 1)

#Sky
sky = loader.loadModel('phase_3.5/models/props/TT_sky.bam')
sky.reparentTo(render)

#Pier
pier = loader.loadModel('phase_4/models/props/piers_tt.bam')
pier.setPos(-63.5335, 41.648, -3.36708)
pier.setHpr(120, 0, 0)
pier.reparentTo(render)

#Tunnel MM

tunnelthree = loader.loadModel('phase_4/models/modules/safe_zone_tunnel_TT.bam')
tunnelthree.reparentTo(render)
tunnelthree.setPos(-239.67,64.08,-6.18)
tunnelthree.setHpr(-90,0,0)
sign = loader.loadModel('phase_3.5/models/props/tunnel_sign_orange.bam')
sign.setScale(1.5, 1, 1.5)
sign.setPos(0, 0, -.18)
sign.reparentTo(tunnelthree.find('**/sign_origin'))
mickey = loader.loadModel('phase_3.5/models/props/mickeySZ.bam')
mickey.setScale(5, 5, 5)
mickey.setY(-0.15)
mickey.reparentTo(tunnelthree.find('**/sign_origin'))

#Gag Shop
gshop = loader.loadModel('phase_4/models/modules/gagShop_TT.bam')
gshop.setPos(-86.6848, -90.5693, 0.500015)
gshop.setHpr(-15, 0, 0)
gshop.reparentTo(render)
door = loader.loadModel('phase_3.5/models/modules/doors_practical.bam').find('**/door_double_square_ur')
door.setColor(1, 0.63, 0.38, 1)
door.reparentTo(gshop.find('**/door_origin'))

#Lightposts
light1 = loader.loadModel('phase_3.5/models/props/streetlight_TT.bam').find('**/prop_post_one_light')
light1.setPos(3.84337, 118.504, 3)
light1.setHpr(-110, 0, 0)
light1.reparentTo(render)

#Trees
tree1 = loader.loadModel('phase_3.5/models/props/trees.bam').find('**/prop_tree_large_ur')
brick = tree1.find('**/prop_tree_large_brickbox_ur')
wood = tree1.find('**/prop_tree_large_woodbox_ur')
brick.removeNode()
wood.removeNode()
tree1.setPos(-128.16, -24.0245, 0.000663757)
tree1.setHpr(135, 0, 0)
tree1.reparentTo(render)

lib = loader.loadModel('phase_4/models/modules/library.bam')
lib.reparentTo(render)
lib.setPos(91.4475,-44.9255,4)
lib.setHpr(180,0,0)
doorlib = loader.loadModel('phase_3.5/models/modules/doors_practical.bam').find('**/door_double_round_ur')
doorlib.setColor(0.88, 0.45, 0.38, 1)
doorlib.reparentTo(lib.find('**/library_door_origin'))

Bank = loader.loadModel('phase_4/models/modules/bank.bam')
Bank.reparentTo(render)
Bank.setPos(57.1796,38.6656,4)
Bank.setHpr(0,0,0)
doorbank = loader.loadModel('phase_3.5/models/modules/doors_practical.bam').find('**/door_double_round_ur')
doorbank.setColor(0.88, 0.45, 0.38, 1)
doorbank.reparentTo(Bank.find('**/bank_door_origin'))
textbank = OnscreenText(text = 'Bank')
#textbank.setPos(0, 0, -1.58)
#textbank.setScale(2.9, 1, 3.4)
#textbank.setKern(0.092795)
textbank.reparentTo(Bank.find('**/sign_origin'))

thall = loader.loadModel('phase_4/models/modules/toonhall.bam')
thall.reparentTo(render)
thall.setPos(116.66,24.29,4)
thall.setHpr(-90,0,-0)
doorthall = loader.loadModel('phase_3.5/models/modules/doors_practical.bam').find('**/door_double_round_ur')
doorthall.setColor(0.88, 0.45, 0.38, 1)
doorthall.reparentTo(thall.find('**/toonhall_door_origin'))

cshop = loader.loadModel('phase_4/models/modules/clothshopTT.bam')
cshop.reparentTo(render)
cshop.setPos(106.265,160.831,3)
cshop.setHpr(-30,0,0)
doorcshop = loader.loadModel('phase_3.5/models/modules/doors_practical.bam').find('**/door_double_clothshop')
doorcshop.setColor(0.88, 0.45, 0.38, 1)
doorcshop.reparentTo(cshop.find('**/door_origin'))

base.useDrive()
run()
```

So now you know the Error and my code, but how do I fix the error?
I have panda.pth in my Python folder so it Enables that instead of the copy of python that came with Panda3D, and my Copy of Python is the same **version** of the Registered copy that came with Panda3D.
So, can Anyone help?

Python Version 2.7.3
Panda3D Version 1.8.1

Comment: add the error message to the question body.

Comment: You should copy paste the error message here instead of giving a link to an image about it. (eg the link might disappear). Anyway it reads better if all the info is embedded to the question and we don't need to go here and there to get the info. It is a SO convention.

Comment: Ok, but there's no way to grab the Error log, because of the console opening, receives error, and instantly closes.

Comment: It 's been a long time since I used windows but I think you can run it from the command line and keep the error in site.

Comment: Ok I was able to obtain a full log of the python script by running It manually: http://pastebin.com/TmuGMNnS

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply; your code references models in relative locations such as `phase_4/models/modules/gagShop_TT.bam`, whereas these files don't exist in their respective locations.  Either place the models it's trying to load in the correct location, or correct the relative path to point to the correct location of the model files.

If these models are present in `.mf` multifiles (which I assume they are because these look to be from Disney's Toontown), you have to mount the Multifile using the virtual file system (see the Panda3D manual), or extract them to disk using the `multify` utility.